# Create select for form django

Tags: django, forms, select, widget, init

I'm trying to create a form where you have to choose a year.
I'm pretty sure this is really  easy, but I don't know why I get some errors.

The main error is this:

```
'AbiturForm' object has no attribute 'fields'
```

My class with the form:

```
class AbiturForm(forms.Form):
    year=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(),required=False)
    abitur=forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    def __init__(self):
        choices=[(x,x) for x in range(1900,2000)]
        self.fields['year'].choices=choices
```

My template:

```
{% extends "home/portal.html" %}

{% block body %}
<div id="content-main">
<div class="module">
<h2>Suche:</h2>
<form action="/suchen/abitur/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><label><b>Jahr:</b></label></td>
        <td>
            <select style="width:200px" name="year" id="year">
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label><b>Abitur?:</b></label></td>
        <td>                
            <input type="checkbox" name="abitur" id="abitur" class="texto"  />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Speichern" class="button"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zsquare is correct, but note that there's no need to override `__init__` unless you want to build the choices dynamically. Usually you would just do it in the declaration:

```
class AbiturForm(forms.Form):
    year = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x, x) for x in range(1900, 2000)], required=False)
```

Couple of points to note: it's probably better to use `ChoiceField` (which defaults to a Select widget already), and please note PEP8 format for spaces around punctuation.

Comment: Thanks, the error is no longer present, but my template is not able to display the select correctly
I tried: 
    <select style="width:200px" name="year" id="year">
    </select>
And:

{{form.as_p}}

The result is the same, a select control without options.

Comment: Please show your view, and the version of the template using `{{ form.as_p }}`.

Comment: I just closed and reopened eclipse and now works perfectly.
Lot of thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Fields is not setup until you call super. Try:

```
class AbiturForm(forms.Form):
    year=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(),required=False)
    abitur=forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    def __init__(self):
        super(AbiturForm, self).__init__()
        choices=[(x,x) for x in range(1900,2000)]
        self.fields['year'].choices=choices
```